# Possible Scenarios to deal with big Linq To Sql model Size

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq-to-sql

I'm working on improving performance of an ERP system which generate a model class of size 1.3MB and 540KB actual size of disk.

**Notes About the project :**

> - The project was developed using ASP.NET WebForms version 4 and C# version 4.0
> - The project will be running on the cloud totally and we may think later of local to online database synchronization.
> - Almost every page in the project calls it's specific class which calls the data model class.

**Simply my questions are  :**

> 1. Does it make sense with the performance side if i try divide this model class ?
>
>    1. What are the possible Scenarios would you suggest to divide that model ?
>    2. What are the Considerations i should take into account before dividing that model ?
>    3. What is the Actual memory Cost of such a big model ? in other words : 1.3MB Class = ...KB/MB on the server RAM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, the assembly size and disk size is irrelevant. If you split it up, you're making more work for assembly-resolution and "fusion", but not enough to care much about. JIT is performed more granularly and on-demand, so will be similar either way.

By all means divide it up for management and logistics reasons, but I'm not sure that I would care much about whether the size of the model class by itself, unless I had good reason (with solid evidence) to think that it was causing a performance issue. I'm also not convinced that 1.3MB is a number I would call "big" (or at least, not big enough to care about).